# Magento get last added products options in cart

Tags: ajax, magento

I am using ajax to add products to cart.when New product added to  cart i want to display its details on right sidebar. I am able to  list simple product, but i am not able to display bundle product options.I used following code to  display cart items to right sidebar

```
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item){
   echo $item->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item){
  $result = array();
  // Load the configured product options
  $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
  // Check for options
  if ($options)
  {
    if (isset($options['options']))
    {
      $result = array_merge($result, $options['options']);
    }
    if (isset($options['additional_options']))
    {
      $result = array_merge($result, $options['additional_options']);
    }
    if (!empty($options['attributes_info']))
    {
      $result = array_merge($options['attributes_info'], $result);
    }
  }
  $finalResult = array_merge($finalResult, $result);
}
```

I think, it can help you.